# Show logs of the application deployed on Cloud Run

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is there any way to see logs.I mean I am able to see logs in log section in cloud run It only show me http log or show me the response(like 403 etc) but does not show me the response like (invalid current password etc.) of error.
I see there is --log-driver gcplogs option but don't know where to configure it I mean its a serverless container so not running any docker run command

Comment: This seems to describe how logs written by your application running on Cloud Run are written to Cloud Logging:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Logging captures stdout and stderr of services (containers) deployed to Google Cloud Run.

You should be able to view these logs either through the the Cloud Console's Logs Viewer (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query) or using `gcloud`.

If you use `gcloud`, you can read the last 15-minutes' (`--freshness=15m`) logs for all Cloud Run services in a project (`${PROJECT}`) with:

```sh
PROJECT="[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]

gcloud logging read \
"resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\"" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--freshness=15m
```

For a specific service's `stderr`:

```
PROJECT=...
SERVICE=...

gcloud logging read \
"resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" resource.labels.service_name=\"${SERVICE}\"" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--freshness=15m
```

To that service's `stderr` text payload only:

```sh
gcloud logging read \
"resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\" resource.labels.service_name=\"${SERVICE}\"" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--freshness=15m \
--format="value(textPayload)"
```

It's a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the full logs buy clicking the popout icon in the `LOGS` pane. This will show all the logs for your Cloud Run service.

[image]

Comment: It again shows only http logs, not logs from application.